# Why numberOfSectionsInTableView is called twice in UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there any other reason (than calling "reloadData") why numberOfSectionsInTableView is called twice? I did debugging and found, that it's get called twice during initial startup when no custom reloadData statements are called.

I have created the table with IB but does that might cause a problem?

Comment: Why do you think this is problem?

Comment: From the user (me) perspective, it seems strange why this method is called twice in normal situation. That's it :) I like to understand my code and what is done beneath it.

Comment: I had the same problem, can't figure out why either..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the call stack. you can see that this method is being called from two different scenarios.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand is it my bug causing that or it's a normal behavior.

Comment: i created a basic navigation proj in xcode. It gets called twice. From the call stack i understand that it is being called for the first time from viewDidAppear (layoutSubviews). The second time it is called by tableview's noteNumberOfRowsChanged. Hence i suppose this is normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your tableView object may instantiate twice. Once i have encountered the same problem due to this.